# importing single .csv into mysql with python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, mysql-python

when running this code i am getting a `Error while connecting to MySQL Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement`

I have tried also to ingest these with another technique

```
import mysql.connector as msql
from mysql.connector import Error
import pandas as pd

empdata = pd.read_csv('path_to_file', index_col=False, delimiter = ',')
empdata.head()

try:
    conn = msql.connect(host='localhost', user='test345',  
                        password='test123')
    if conn.is_connected():
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE timetheft")
        print("Database is created")
except Error as e:
    print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)

try:
    conn = msql.connect(host='localhost', database='timetheft', user='test345', password='test123')
    if conn.is_connected():
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select database();")
        record = cursor.fetchone()
        print("You're connected to database: ", record)
        cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS company;')
        print('Creating table....')
        create_contracts_table = """
         CREATE TABLE company ( ID VARCHAR(40) PRIMARY KEY, 
        Company_Name VARCHAR(40), 
        Country VARCHAR(40), 
        City VARCHAR(40), 
        Email VARCHAR(40),  
        Industry VARCHAR(30),
        Employees VARCHAR(30)
        );
        """
        cursor.execute(create_company_table)
        print("Table is created....")
        for i,row in empdata.iterrows():
            sql = "INSERT INTO timetheft.company VALUES (%S, %S, %S, %S, %S,%S,%S,%S)"
            cursor.execute(sql, tuple(row))
            print("Record inserted")
            # the connection is not auto committed by default, so we must commit to save our changes
            conn.commit()
except Error as e:
            print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
```

second technique I tried

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path_to_file'  
INTO TABLE copmany  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'   
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

worked better but many errors. only 20% of rows ingested.

Finally here is an excerpt from the .csv  (data is consistent throughout all 1K rows)

"ID";"Company_Name";"Country";"City";"Email";"Industry";"Employees"
217520699;"Enim Corp.";"Germany";"Bamberg";"posuere@diamvel.edu";"Internet";"51-100"
352428999;"Lacus Vestibulum Consulting";"Germany";"Villingen-Schwenningen";"egestas@lacusEtiambibendum.org";"Food Production";"100-500"
371718299;"Dictum Ultricies Ltd";"Germany";"Anklam";"convallis.erat@sempercursus.co.uk";"Primary/Secondary Education";"100-500"
676789799;"A Consulting";"Germany";"Andernach";"massa@etrisusQuisque.ca";"Government Relations";"100-500"
718526699;"Odio LLP";"Germany";"Eisenhüttenstadt";"Quisque.varius@euismod.org";"E-Learning";"11-50"

Comment: Your table has seven columns, but your insert statement has eight placeholders.

Comment: yes but this is not the root of the issue. Tried with 7 placeholders as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed these issues to get the code to work:

- make the number of placeholders in the insert statement equal to the number of columns
- the placeholders should be lower-case `'%s'`
- the cell delimiter appears to be a semi-colon, not a comma.

For simply reading a csv with ~1000 rows Pandas is overkill (and iterrows seems not to behave as you expect).  I've used the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module from the standard library instead.

```py
import csv 

...

sql = "INSERT INTO company VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"

with open("67359903.csv", "r", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")
    # Skip the header row.
    next(reader)
    # For large files it may be more efficient to commit 
    # rows in batches.
    cursor.executemany(sql, reader)
    conn.commit()
```

If using the `csv` module is not convenient, the dataframe's  [itertuples](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html#pandas.DataFrame.itertuples) method may be used to iterate over the data:

```py
empdata = pd.read_csv('67359903.csv', index_col=False, delimiter=';')

for tuple_ in empdata.itertuples(index=False):
    cursor.execute(sql, tuple_)
conn.commit()
```

Or the [dataframe can be dumped to the database](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html?highlight=to_sql#pandas.DataFrame.to_sql) directly.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector:///test')
empdata.to_sql('company', engine, index=False, if_exists='replace')
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it still gives me same error. And i have a second .csv with over 50MB and i think 1,5 million rows.. :/

Comment: I've added two ways to load the table using Pandas .  All three work with the data provided in the question, with the assumption that each row of data is separated by a newline.

Comment: thanks so much! the sqlalchemy dump worked wonders! I could not reproduce it with itertuples, got same argument error from SQL. Thanks again!